# hr makes the parent div resize to 100% in IE7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have the following div

```
<body>
<span style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block">
    Some text<br />
    <hr />
    some more text
</span>
</body>
```

In "normal" web browsers, the width of the div is calculated to fit the text. And the `hr` is 100% of the div.
[image]

But in IE7 the `hr` causes the div to expand to 100% of the body.
[image]

Is there any clever css I need to add somewhere so it behaves correctly in IE7?

Please note, I can't set any fixed width.

Comment: I hope you realize a `span` is _not_ a `div`. Also, `display:inline-block` pretty sure IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`

Comment: I started with a div then I saw a post saying I should use a `span` with `display:inline-block` to solve this kind of issue. But it didn't work in this case.

Comment: Try adding the property `width: 100% !important` to your <hr />. Just add some class.
P.S.: Using arbitrarily styles in your HTML here and there is a very BAD practice.

Comment: @Ecko didn't work I'm afraid. Inline styles are only here for the example. In real life I keep it all in a CSS file!

Comment: @Johann: Can you post your entire HTML/CSS code here in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Ecko I wanted to jsfiffle it, but it seems jsfiddle.net is down today from my side of the globe :( In any case, you don't need anything else but the code in the question to see the "bug"

Comment: @TheZ - IE6 is perfectly happy with `inline-block` as long as the element's default style is `inline`. It's a well known IE7 quirk.

Comment: @Spudley Indeed you are right, I was mistaken: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `width` property of the `<hr>` tag has been deprecated, so you're styling options are limited on the `<hr>` tag.

- [15.3 Rules: the HR element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-HR)
- [Index of Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html)

A more modern approach is to use the `border` property of a `<div>` instead.

*Image rendered by IE 7:*

[image]

*Image rendered by Chrome 19:*

[image]

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4QEu9/2/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div style="border:1px solid red; float:left;">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
    <p class="border-top">
      some more text
    </p>
  </div>
</body>​​​
```

**CSS**

```
​.border-top{
  border-top:#000 1px solid;
  padding-top:1em;
}​
```

**Note:** IE 6 & 7 don't support `display:inline-block`, so you might need to use `float:left` instead.  The article below compares the use of the aforementioned properties:

- [CSS display: inline-Block: Why It Rocks, And Why It Sucks](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this causes the same issue as the original code in IE7 I'm afraid!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the HTML attributes for the `hr` tag have been deprecated (`align`, `noshade`, `size`, `width`), in favor of CSS styling, but the `hr` tag itself has not been deprecated.

Comment: Matt Coughlin, you are right. I had the wrong idea all this time. Some propperties have been deprecated for `<hr />`, but not the tag itself. Thanks! (I'm revising my answer)

Answer (score 1):

In IE6/7, `display:inline-block` only works on elements that are inline by default (e.g., span). So if you try setting a div to `display:inline-block`, it won't work in IE6/7.

An inline element will size itself to the width of its content. An inline-block element will do the same by default, if it's not given an explicit width. If the hr is 100% (100% of its parent, which in turn is 100% of the child), then there's a circular definition for the hr width that may not work as expected (100% of what? 100% of itself).

To avoid a circular definition for the width that may not work as expected in some browsers (especially IE6/7), either the container of the hr (div, span, or whatever) should have a defined width (in px, %, or em) or the hr itself should have an explicit width (in px or em). Otherwise, the width is not defined in any identifiable way, and it's left up to the browser to decide what to do by default.

If you can't set any widths, that may rule out using an `hr` tag. And based on the tests I ran, the options don't look very good for CSS solutions either (without setting a width).

**Edit:**

I think the only way to do this without setting widths or relying on JavaScript or jQuery, is if it's acceptable to have a horizontal line after every line of text (including any long paragraphs that wrap around to the next line, if there are any). In that case you could add a bg image to the container that contains a horizontal line at increments equal to the line-height of the text, displayed at a vertical offset equal to the line-height so a line doesn't appear at the top of the first line of text.

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <p>This is the first line.<br/>
       This is the second line.<br/>
       This is a long line that will wrap around to the next line if the container is not very wide.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
    background: url(image.png) repeat-x left 15px;
}
p {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myUGt/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a method at a blog. The original one required `modernizer.js`. I've edited it.

HTML:
`<div class="hrdemo"><hr /></div>`

CSS:
`.hrdemo hr {
    display:none
}`

However, if your `div.hrdemo` is inside some floated container; you may have to assign a fixed width for it (for IE7).